# Gradle. Could not resolving dependencies from my custom lib using in another project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have buld.gradle using for my custom library:

```
ext {
    serenity_version = "2.0.82"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.7.10'
}

jar {
    from {
        zip64 = true
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

I have built and uploaded my jar to Nexus Repository Manager and when I try to use this lib in another project, my IDE (IntelliJ) could not see any function from 'com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.7.10'. But I see that lib dowloaded and available (com.company:library:0.0.1) and I can call any my custom function from my class from lib.

build.gradle from main project:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "path to nexus repo" }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'com.company:library:0.0.1'
}
```

I want to use 'com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.7.10' in main project without adding additional dependencies to build.gradle main project  - is it possible?

Comment: Do you want `'com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.7.10` to be downloaded from nexus ?

Comment: Yes, because I am going to use `com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.7.10` dependency in main project as well

Comment: I haven't used nexus. Are you running it locally ? If you are using it locally, I think you have to specify that repository in the `repositories` block

Comment: I specify nexus repo in build.gradle main project `maven { url "path to nexus repo" }` and successfully dowloaded it and can use custom classes from lib except `com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.7.10` class

Comment: Can you build by Gradle from command line?

Comment: `when I try to use this lib in another project, my IDE (IntelliJ) could not see any function from 'com.couchbase.client:java-client:2.7.10'. But I see that lib dowloaded and available (com.company:library:0.0.1) and I can call any my custom function from my class from lib.` Does IDE build work? Attach screenshot describing the problem you see in IDE.